# Strange behavior with GoogleMobileAds sdk

Tags: ios, swift, admob

When I put this method in `application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

`GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "MYAPPID")`

My ads show up as expected.

However, as soon as I move the `GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "MYAPPID")` to a helper method located inside a library framework, and call that helper method instead, the ads do not show up. And there is no log in the console that indicates what's wrong as far as I can tell.

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: - (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)bannerView didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error; use this delegates method for get error of ads

Comment: The error is "no ad to load". However there is no error when I call `GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "MYAPPID")` directly in my App Delegate.

Comment: check your ad id with your bundle identifier

Comment: They are correct

Comment: which kind of adv you use like bannner adv , GADInterstitial , etc ?

Comment: This is for banner ad.

Comment: Check my answer thats helps you.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0**

Use this delegates in

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , GADBannerViewDelegate{

     // put this line in viewdidload()
     let bannerview1 : GADBannerView = GADBannerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 50))
     bannerview1.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
     bannerview1.rootViewController = self
     bannerview1.delegate = self
     bannerview1.load(GADRequest())
     self.view.addSubview(bannerview1)

 // Delegates for adv error

    func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
        print(error)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A part from [Google Admob Documentation for iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/quick-start):

> **Initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK**
>
> At app launch, initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK by calling
> configureWithApplicationID: in the
> application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method of AppDelegate.m or
> AppDelegate.swift. Objective-CSwift AppDelegate.m
>
> ```
> - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
>     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
>
>   // Use Firebase library to configure APIs
>   [FIRApp configure];
>   [GADMobileAds configureWithApplicationID:@"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~1458002511"];
>   return YES;
> }
> ```
>
> Initializing the Google Mobile Ads SDK at app launch allows the SDK to
> fetch app-level settings and perform configuration tasks as early as
> possible. This can help reduce latency for the initial ad request.
> Initialization requires an app ID. App IDs are unique identifiers
> given to mobile apps when they're registered in the AdMob console.

So, IMHO, you *must* have to call this configure function on application launch.

Hope that helps!