# Google admob successfully loaded but not show

Tags: ios, swift3, admob

I have multiple viewcontrollers on my app and I would like to add google ad to two of my viewcontrollers. The first one is a tableviewcontroller and I successfully added the ad by following google tutorial. However, I can seem to get ad shown on second viewcontroller which contains scrollview. I'm placing GADBannerView(Green box) on top of the scrollview controller as shown in the following screencap :

[image: The green box is GADBannerView]

[image]

I checked if adViewDidReceiveAd method gets called and it is in fact gets called. However, the ad isn't shown. Here's my code snippet

```
func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
    //print("Banner loaded successfully")

    // Reposition the banner ad to create a slide down effect
    let translateTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -bannerView.bounds.size.height)
    bannerView.transform = translateTransform

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        bannerView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    }

    self.adBanner = bannerView
}
```

Comment: show your runtime screen .

Comment: It doesn't show anything. There's nothing there in greenbox area.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43199293/6656894 refer this

Comment: if still not solve then refer this complete demo https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/quick-start

Comment: I found out what I was doing wrong. Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody having the same issue..it was just my stupid mistake. I created uiview in the Interface Builder and created another one programmatically which is used to set all the parameters of admob. When the delegate method is called, I tried to assign my view with the one passed as a parameter. My solution is just setting the admob parameters for the view I created in IB.